# mediastreamvalidator showing "Illegal MIME type" `application/x-mpegURL`

Tags: http-live-streaming

I ran an m3u8 manifest through `mediastreamvalidator` and then through `hlsreport` and the first error under "Must Fix Issues" is this:

```
1. Illegal MIME type

    All Variants, MIME type: application/x-mpegURL
    All Renditions, MIME type: application/x-mpegURL
    Master Playlist, MIME type: application/x-mpegURL
```

I'm a bit confused because `application/x-mpegURL` is the [apple-recommended](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming/DeployingHTTPLiveStreaming.html) MIME type for m3u8 streams. How do I make sense of this?

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I think only `audio/mpegURL` and `application/vnd.apple.mpegURL` are accepted by the program.